# Добавить значение в коллекцию Laravel

Tags: laravel

Получаю коллекцию пользователя, как мне добавить значение в эту коллекцию, как будто это запись с выборки БД?
При таком коде он добавляет значение, но как бы отдельно от коллекции.

```
$user = User::find(1);

$user->put('age', 35);

dd($user);
```

Вот что хотелось бы получить

```
#attributes: array:43 [
        "id" => 1
        "created_at" => "2020-04-04 08:36:25"
        "updated_at" => "2020-04-04 08:36:25"
        "child_surname" => "Петров"
        "child_name" => "Алексей"
        "age" => "35"
        .......
```

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, что Вы пытаетесь сделать. Получить коллекцию всех пользователей и добавить им всем одни и те же значения полей?
Или получить конкретного пользователя и обновить ему данные?

Если первое, то как то так

```
User::where()->update(['age' => 35]);
```

Если второе, то надо использовать:

```
User::find(1);
$user->age = 35;
$user->save();
```

Вообще, документация отвечает на этот вопрос :)

[Документация laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#updates)

Comment: Это совсем не то, мне не надо добавлять в базу данные, а в коллекцию добавить значения

Comment: @Федотов

 ::find(1) в вашем случае возвращает один объект, у которого первичный ключ, в данном случае id == 1. Это не коллекция. У объекта есть атрибуты. Вы хотите добавить этому объекту атрибут age равный 35. Для этого можно использовать $user->age = 35. Если не хотите писать в базу - не добавляйте $user->save()